# Use and meaning of WOULD

Tags: modal-verbs, subjunctives, past-participles, will-would, conditionals

Could you please explain me what is the use and the meaning of WOULD in this sentence?

“It’s very odd that he WOULD HAVE BEHAVED rudely to you”.

Thank you!
Francesca

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. On this site, the users try to explain how they tried to find out the answer themselves first and what are their doubts. Any grammar gives explanations of this.

Answer (score 0):

*Would* is a modal verb. The following [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs) discusses them in depth.